# Why I get nan for Keras loss?

Tags: python, keras, nan, loss

I am following the article https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/10/predicting-stock-price-machine-learningnd-deep-learning-techniques-python/ .

First, I try to use the data in the article, i.e., https://s3-ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/av-blog-media/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/NSE-TATAGLOBAL11.csv . The  script produces the same result as the article.

Then, I try to download another data set from Yahoo Finance. THe data set is larger(2805 rows rather than 1000+ rows in the article sample data set). However, after using LSTM method, I will get the loss as nan. Why? How to solve the problem?

Comment: check whether the data use are using have any `nan` in it

Comment: There are a lot of factors that count, you can try the following:
1. Change your model to a simpler model
2. Changing the data type (such as Float32 to Float64)
3. Verify if the input is containing non-numeric characters
4. Check if any divide by zero computation occurs

Comment: @SreeramTP, Thank you very much. There are several lines with null values. After removing them, everything is fine.

Comment: I have put up my comment as answer. If it helped consider accepting the answer so that others can see the issue is closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably the data your are using will contain `nan`. Removing those rows or filling those rows with appropriate values will fix the issue.

You can check for `nan` using `np.isnan(X)`

Answer (score 0):

follow the below step by step :

1. Normalize your data by quantile normalizing, To be rigorous, compute this transformation on the training data, not on the entire dataset.
2. Add regularization, either by increasing the dropout rate or adding L1 and L2 penalties to the weights. L1 regularization is analogous to feature selection.
3. If these still don't help, reduce the size of your network to decrease the network parameters that caused train with less data. This is not always the best idea since it can harm performance.
4. finally, Increase the batch size, it could potentially increase the stability of the optimization.